# Combobox SelectedItem shows old value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have the following ComboBox inside a grid:

```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
       <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
           <Binding Path="SelectedCat" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
               <Binding.ValidationRules>
                   <MyValidation/>
               </Binding.ValidationRules>
           </Binding>
       </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
   </ComboBox>
```

Categories is an ObservableCollection while SelecetedCat is defined as follows:

```
private string m_selectedCat;
public string SelectedCat
{
    get { return m_selectedCat; }
    set
    {
        m_selectedCat = value;
        if (value == "--reset--")
        {
            var dlg = new CatDialog();
            var res = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (res == true)
            {
                var newCat = dlg.Text;
                Categories.Add(newCat);
                SelectedCat = newCat;
            }
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCat");
    }
}
```

Now, when I select "--reset--" from the combobox, the CatDialog shows up letting me insert a new Cat string which I have to insert in the Categories property, selecting it right after.

The problem is that the setter is recalled right after Categories.Add(newCat); is executed. At that time, the value keyword still is "--reset--" and the the dialog is recalled for a second time, while i already provided the desired Cat.

Any way to fix that please?

Regards,
FZ

Comment: isnt it bad style within the setter --> SelectedCat = newCat; and why m_selectedCategory = value; is set and return m_selectedCat; is get?

Comment: It was a typo. I just updated the code with the correct one.

Comment: SelectedCat = newCat; within the setter is still bad style. it should be m_selectedCat = newCat;

Comment: Of course, your comment is correct but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: It sounds like `Categories.Add()` is the problem.  Try doing `m-selectedCat = newCat; Categories.Add(newCat);` instead.  I think I have heard something about ObservableCollections notifying for updates when `.Add()` is called, or something like that.

Comment: I also tried that, but this doesn't fix the issue. In fact, value keyword is not affected when you use m_selectedCat = newCat; statement.
The problem seems to me that the ObservableCollection invalidates and force immediate refresh of the SelectedItem object, prior this can be updated